# How to forbid multi-line lambdas by static analysis?

Tags: java, maven, static-analysis, checkstyle

I have a legacy code base which suffers a lot from lengthy lambdas like this.

```
collection.forEach(item -> { 
   // 100 lines of logic buried here
});
```

Most of them can be refactored to classes implementing `Callable`, `Runnable` or `Consumer`, which would greatly improve readability of code.

How can I enforce separate classes for lambdas of more than one expressions (preferably by checkstyle)?
I want to see as few `... -> { ...; }` as possible, but `... -> ...` is fine.

Comment: Do you already have a static analysis framework in place that you can add checks to?

Comment: I got checkstyle, mentioned it and added to tags

Comment: For now there is no good way to do it. I think it can be done with regexp check(s), but it can be error-prone. 
Thank you for idea, I have created new feature request in checkstyle repo for it. https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/8341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since checkstyle 8.37 you can use [LambdaBodyLengthCheck](https://checkstyle.org/config_sizes.html#LambdaBodyLength), it does exactly what you want. You can specify max length of lambda body, by default it is 10.